# background color for qtreeview when checkbox is placed in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I have set background color for QTreeView and the view has QCheckBox also.So in the delegate i have drawn the QCheckbox but the remaining area of the cell where my QCheckbox is placedhas no background color.I understand QRect takes the whole cell and paints the check box but how do i say to paint the remaining are of cell(apart form QCheckBox) with my background color.

thanks,

Comment: Why do you paint the check box yourself instead of letting QTreeView do that?

Comment: only few rows has bool values which i'm replacing by QCheckBox in paint method of MyDelegate.

Comment: You could achieve it with your tree view model, using `Qt::BackgroundRole` in your model's data() function, and `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` in your model's flags() function.

Comment: So your trying to say we need to create custom model just for creating QCheckBox but isnt there an way that i can achieve this in paint of my delegate itself.

Comment: Hm, how do you use `QTreeView` without a model? Maybe you mean `QTreeWidget`? These are different classes, btw. You mentioned QTreeView, so that I am talking about its model.

Comment: Yeah Ofcourse im using Model/View .But  your saying to  override data() of model.But im using QStandardItemModel,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51755/discussion-between-anbu-selvan-and-vahancho)